# default value for JAX-RS POST bean property

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, swagger

I have the following JAX-RS resource:

```
@POST
public Response createPerson(
                final User user) {
    ...
}
```

and User bean is:

```
public class User {
    protected String lastName;
    protected String role;
    @DefaultValue("true")
    protected Boolean active;
    @DefaultValue("dd.MM.yyyy")
    protected String dateFormat;
...//getters and setters
}
```

When I don't specify values for 'active' and 'dateFormat' I expect them to be filled with default values. But they are null.

I've read docs for `@DefaultValue` and it seems to be not suitable for my scenario. But how can I ask jersey to fill these absent properties wiith defaults?

**Edit**:
I want to use annotations instead of the code (e.g. in constructor) because I want to be able to automatically generate API documentation (e.g. swagger). Swagger already supports `@DefaultValue` when providing parameter info, but I can extend it, if another approach with annotations is used.

Of course I can use code together with swagger-specific annotations, but this leads to duplications. I'd rather use same meta-info to get both application logic and documentation. I'm ok with custom annotations, while extending both jersey and swagger.

Answer (score 4):

You could set the defaults either directly in the class definition or in the no-arg constructor, all in plain old java, no need for any annotations. When using the primitive type instead of the wrapper, active would default to false.

Just as an example:

```
public static class User {
    public boolean primActive;
    public Boolean wrapActive;
    public boolean consActive;

    public User() {
        consActive = true;
    }
}
```

The resource:

```
@POST
@Path("foo")
public User getUser( User user ) {
    return user;
}
```

When posting an empty request (when using json: `{}`), the following is returned.

```
{
    primActive: false
    consActive: true
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer completely solves my initial described problem. But I want solution with annotations, so that I can use this information when generating API documentation (see my edits)